# CSS Selectors (in Selenium Webdriver) could not recognize dynamically generated scripts

Tags: css, selenium

I would need help for the following

**Requirement:** There is a navigation menu bar at the top of the homepage which displays differently upon scrolling down, which means that the class name of the body changes from "home" to "home scriptable persistant-on" which i need to validate in my selenium Webdriver Tests scripts.

**Problem stmt:** The problem is when i use CSS selectors to identify the element (by classname), it doesn't recognize because it is dynamic and because the pagesource only displays body="home" rather than "home scriptable persistant-on" even after scrolling. Please find below the following snippet of the code. I've also tried other CSS selectors, but didn't work out. Not sure how to handle this. Can anyone help me on this, that'll be really helpful as i need to complete this asap and i got struck in this.

```html
<body class="home scriptable persistent-on">
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
            /* UI NOTE: - the page is designed by default to function with scripts turned off (for accessibility reasons) adding the class of "scriptable" dynamically allows us to target CSS to users with JavaScript enabled - this is the ONLY piece of JavaScript that should be executed at the top of the page */
            document.body.className += " scriptable";
        //]]>
          
 ...
          
</body>
 
 I'm using the following code
 
 private static final By BODY_FOR_STICKY_NAV = By.cssSelector("body.home.scriptable.persistent-on");
 driver.findElement(BODY_FOR_STICKY_NAV)
 
 I've tried using different ways in CSS selectors..nothing works out
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you select the successfully just using "home" before scrolling?

Comment: Even if the page source doesn't show the update class in your browser's console, you should still be able to select the element by it's new classname with Selenium. Did you try selecting by css "home scriptable persistant-on" to see if it actually returns anything?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pat..Yes, I tried selecting "home scritable persistan-on" element.. but it throws component not found exception.. I can only see this element in inspect element, but in page source it only shows "home" source since it is dynamic..not sure how to proceed..

Comment: Can you show the exact code for the selector you tried which didn't work?

Comment: I'm trying to identify using the following   By.cssSelector("body.home.scriptable.persistent-on");

Comment: Are you waiting for any expectedCondition? Your findElement() might be executing before the page finished scrolling.

Comment: Are you able to successfully select the element by css "home" before scrolling?

Comment: The expected condition is when i scroll down the page, the sticky navigation should appear on top since the original navigation bar will not appear as you scroll down. it is like freezing the 1st row in spreadsheet. And as you said, i shall try to wait for couple of seconds before i find the element.

Comment: ExpectedCondition is a Selenium object. I'll post it as answer... But if you weren't able to select it even with "home" before scrolling, then this answer won't help. Something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your findElement() might be executing before the page finishes scrolling. You can avoid this by waiting for an expected condition.

```
// execute code to scroll the page to the desired position to trigger the class change

// then wait for the element to get the class
Wait<WebDriver> wait= new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.css(".home.scriptable.persistent-on")));
```

Comment: No luck Pat..still it shows the following org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body.home.scriptable.persistent-on"}

Comment: I got it resolved..what happened was the page which i'm trying to build up thru dataprovider with contents doesn't have enough contents to scroll the page, hence it failed. So i have added few more contents to get that up..and it worked..But Thanks for your help and sorry for the late reply..

Comment: No worries. You might want to post your solution as an answer, and then accept it.